# Algebraic Aproach For this word problem

Tags: linear-algebra

How can the followin question be solved algebraically?

A certain dealership has a total of 100 vehicles consisting of cars and trucks. 1/2 of the cars are used and 1/3 of the trucks are used. If there are 42 used vehicles used altogether, how many trucks are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\xu}{x^{\text{used}}}
\newcommand{\yu}{y^{\text{used}}}
\newcommand{\xn}{x^{\text{new}}}
\newcommand{\yn}{y^{\text{new}}}
$
The **key** in converting text problems into algebraic expressions is to  write an expression for every sentence or phrase which contains quantifiable information.

---

For example, consider your problem

> A certain dealership has a total of $100$ vehicles consisting of cars and trucks. 
>   $1/2$ of the cars are used and $1/3$ of the trucks are used. 
>   If there are $42$ used vehicles used altogether, how many trucks are there?

Let us disassemble it into set of statements working with on at a time:

1. > A certain dealership has a total of $100$ vehicles consisting of cars and trucks.

   Let  $x, y$ be the *total* number of cars and trucks respectively. 
   Then we write the first equation
   $$
   x + y = 100
   $$
2. > $1/2$ of the cars are used and $1/3$ of the trucks are used.

   Note that in this sentence we have **two** statemnts, so let us deal with them separately.

   Denote $\xn$ and $\yn$ the number of *new* cars and trucks, $\xu$, $\yu$ – number of *used* cars and trucks, then we can write the second and the third equations

   > > $1/2$ of the cars are used $(\dots)$

   $$
     \xu = \frac{1}{2} x 
     $$

   > > $(\dots)$ and $1/3$ of the trucks are used

   $$
     \yu = \frac{1}{3} y
     $$
3. > If there are $42$ used vehicles used altogether, how many trucks are there?

   The last sentence contains one quantitate statement and states the question for problem

   > > If there are $42$ used vehicles used altogether, $( \dots ) $

   $$\xu + \yu = 42$$

   and states the question for problem

   > > how many trucks are there?

   which can be written in our notation as "find $y$""
   $$
       y \quad - \quad  ?
       $$

---

Finally, combining items $1$ to $3$, we write the system of equations, which is the algebraic formulation of the original text problem:

> $
> \begin{aligned}
> \text{Find } y \text{ given } \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad 
> \begin{cases}
> x+ y = 100, \\
> \xu = \dfrac{1}{2} x, \\
> \yu = \dfrac{1}{3} y, \\
> \xu + \yu = 42,  
> \end{cases}
> \end{aligned}
> $

Furthermore, we can simplify the system and write 
$$
\begin{cases}
x + y = 100, \\
\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{3} y = 42,
\end{cases} 
$$

which is easy to solve: 
$$
\begin{cases}
x + y = 100, \\
\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{3} y = 42,
\end{cases} 
\implies
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{2}y = 50, \\
\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{3} y = 42,
\end{cases} 
\implies
\begin{cases}
\left(\dfrac{1}{2} x - \dfrac{1}{2} x  \right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{2} y - \dfrac{1}{3} y  \right) = 50 - 42, \\
\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{3} y = 42,
\end{cases} 
\implies
\dfrac{1}{6}y = 8 \implies y = 48
$$

Thus, the final answer is

> There are $48$ trucks at the dealership.

Comment: Well organized and nice explanation +1 ^^

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ denote the number of cars, and $y$ denote the number of trucks:

There are $100$ vehicles consisting of cars and trucks, so:

$$
x+y = 100
$$

Also, we have $1/2$ of the cars is used that is the number of used cars is $x/2$, and $1/3$ of the number of trucks is used which means $y/3$, and the total sums up to 42. We then get:

$$
\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{3} = 42
$$

Now you have a system of equations:

$$
x+y = 100 \\
\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{3} = 42
$$

Let's solve it:

$$
x+y = 100 \\
3x+2y =252\\ 
$$
$$
3x+3y = 300 \\
3x+2y =252\\\\
$$

substracting the first from the second we get:

$y = 48$ which is the number of trucks